# Problems trying to connect to website over FTP in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently trying to connect to a website over ftp in Visual Studio 2010. Unfortunately, Visual Studio takes about ten minutes to connect as it would appear that it is trying to walk all the folders on the remote site (at least that's my assumption).

Upon doing further research, I was able to find a bug report and a [hotfix](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958094) from 2009, but nothing about Visual Studio 2010. Is this the same bug or am I doing something else wrong?

I have read [*Visual Studio 2010 hangs when opening websites*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694544/visual-studio-2010-hangs-when-opening-websites), but my extensions are all up to date.

For more information, I am currently running Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP. The extensions/addons/tools for Visual Studio I have installed are

- [Nuget Package Manager](https://www.nuget.org/)
- [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)
- [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/)
- [MVVM Light Toolkit](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)
- [TextHighlighterExtension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6706b602-6f10-4fd1-8e14-75840f855569)

I'm attempting to connect to the server over plain ftp

**Edit**: After further experimentation, it would appear that it is in fact one of my extensions that's causing the problem. I've removed the TextHighlighterExtension for now and am searching for reports of any other extensions causing problems with FTP. Any ideas?

Comment: Generally, VS2010 lags when trying to access a remote site directly under the best of circumstances. My guess is your issue is resharper, since it scans lots of files. either way, I really recommend you copy the files locally, and work with them on your hdd. It will give you the best experience.